# display text file using nested array structure

Tags: c++

I'm using nested array structure and multiple for loop to display the text file like following:

[image]

but the loop is stop at second line and i dunno what is the problem..
can someone help for this?

example text file

```
1204042,Alexa Danvers,012-4567891,alex@hotmail.com,S01,Science,A,S02,Art,B,S03,Music,B,S04,Math,A,
1204137,Goh Xin Chan,013-4587212,gohxin@hotmail.com,S01,Science,B,S02,Art,B,
1204675,Liu Xiao Meng,012-5647891,liu_96@hotmail.com,S03,Music,A,S04,Math,A,S05,English,C,
```

//read

```
for (int i = 1; i <= maxInfo; i++)
{
    inFile.getline(record[i].id, 15, ',');
    inFile.getline(record[i].name, 40, ',');
    inFile.getline(record[i].phone, 15, ',');
    inFile.getline(record[i].email, 30, ',');


    for (int j = 1; j <= 5; j++)
    {
        inFile.getline(record[i].subjects[j].code, 6, ',');
        inFile.getline(record[i].subjects[j].subName, 15, ',');
        inFile.getline(record[i].subjects[j].grade, 5, ',');
    }
}
```

//display

```
for (int i = 1; i <= maxInfo; i++)
{
    cout << setw(2) << left << i << ".  " << setw(14) << left << record[i].id << setw(20);
    cout << record[i].name << setw(20) << record[i].phone << setw(32) << record[i].email;

    for (int j = 1; j <= 5; j++)
    {
        cout << "" << setw(18) << record[i].subjects[j].code << setw(18)
            << record[i].subjects[j].subName << setw(18)
            << record[i].subjects[j].grade << "\n"  << setw(91);

    }

}
```

Comment: Give atleast 2 records from your text file as example. Might be a text file problem

Comment: hi this is the example from text file..
1709,John Tey,0185214678,johna99@gmail.com,S04,Math,D,S05,English,F,
1805,ConXing,0125214789,chong@hotmail.com,S03,Music,B,S04,Math,A,
1888,John,0174985612,tab@gmail.com,S01,Science,C,S02,Art,B,S04,Math,A,

Comment: Add this to your post, not in comment. Plus [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/22671786#) it please to make it clearer

Answer (score 0):

You are reading code, subName and grade up to 5 times. What happens when reading the first line is that on the 5th read, there is no such data and it stops at the newline character. Therefore, the 5th iteration read of subName and grade will actually be reading the second line.

A better way of reading would be to read the entire line as a string, then format the string into your data structures, and deciding how many loops there are for reading subjects by counting the number of ',' present in the string or terminating at the end of string.

Comment: i had solve the problem with "inFile.peek()"..btw thanks for your comment.